# "The local variable may not have been initialized" error

Tags: java, image

I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting this error, despite researching it a little. I'm trying to make a program that looks through an image and finds out which color there is more of. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the file name:");
int red    =  0;
int orange =  0;
int yellow =  0;
int green  =  0;
int blue   =  0;
int violet =  0;
void setup(){
  size(1920,1080);
  PImage picture = loadImage("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Downloads\\NMS" + fileName + ".png");
  image(picture,0,0);
  colorReader();
}

int colorReader(){
  for(int row; row<=1920; row++){           < ((Here is the error))
    for(int column; column<=1080; column++){
      color color1 = get(row,column);
      int redColor = (int)red(color1);
      int greenColor = (int)green(color1);
      int blueColor = (int)blue(color1);
      if(255-redColor<=127 && 255-greenColor<=191 && 255-blueColor<=191)
        red++;
      if(255-redColor<=127 && 255-greenColor<=159 && 255-blueColor<=191)
        orange++;
      if(255-redColor<=127 && 255-greenColor<=127 && 255-blueColor<=191)
        yellow++;
      if(255-redColor<=191 && 255-greenColor<=127 && 255-blueColor<=191)
        green++;
      if(255-redColor<=191 && 255-greenColor<=191 && 255-blueColor<=127)
        blue++;
      if(255-redColor<=159 && 255-greenColor<=191 && 255-blueColor<=159)
        violet++;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("There is more ");
  if(red> orange && red>yellow && red>green && red>blue && red>violet)
    System.out.print("red ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  if(orange> red && orange>yellow && orange>green && orange>blue && orange>violet)
    System.out.print("orange ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  if(yellow> orange && yellow>red && yellow>green && yellow>blue && yellow>violet)
    System.out.print("yellow ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  if(green> orange && green>yellow && green>red && green>blue && green>violet)
    System.out.print("green ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  if(blue> orange && blue>yellow && blue>green && blue>red && blue>violet)
    System.out.print("blue ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  if(violet> orange && violet>yellow && violet>green && violet>blue && violet>red)
    System.out.print("violet ");
  else
    System.out.print("IT'S A TIE!");
  System.out.print("than anything else in this picture.");
  int warm = red + orange + yellow;
  int cool = green + blue + violet;
  if(warm>cool)
    System.out.println("There are also more warm colors than cool.");
  if(cool>warm)
    System.out.println("There are also more cool colors than warm.");
  if(cool==warm)
    System.out.println("The amount of warm and cool colors are even.");
  return 0;
}
```

It's giving me issues with the "row" variable saying that it's not initialized. What does it mean by that? Thanks!

Edit: Also, I know that I reeeaaally messed up on the logic. I'm working on fixing that.

Comment: Use `int row=0;` Local variables should be initialized before use.

Comment: Tim, did either of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. You may still accept an answer on a closed question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
 for(int row; row<=1920; row++){
```

You are not initializing the row integer to any value. Try

```
 for(int row = 0; row<=1920; row++){
```

Recall that the syntax for the `for` loop in Java requires initialization in the first argument. Declaring a variable `int row` does not qualify as initialization.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. I've done thousands of for loops, before, so I'm not sure why I forgot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
for(int row = 0; row<=1920; row++){
```

A `for` loop of this form must initialise the loop variable in the first part of the `for` clause, as [per the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

```
for(init clause; expression; for update)
```